# Count of successive similar strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data-frame:

```
   Id  Seqno. Event
    1     2    A 
    1     3    B 
    1     5    A 
    1     6    A 
    1     7    A 
    1     8    B 
    1     9    C 
    1    10    D
```

I want to filter the data-frame according to the time "Event A happened successively". For example if i try 
Event A > 2 it should return all the Ids as

```
 Id Event count 
  1  A   3
```

So far I have tried

```
   df['new'] = df['Event'].shift()+ df['Event']

   a= df[df['new']=='AA']

   a[a['Id'].isin(a['Id'].value_counts()[a['Id'].value_counts()>2].index)]
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Look at value_counts

Comment: Whats is the desired output?

Comment: @W-B Thanks! I am only interested in successive events and I don't think value_counts will be helpful. I already tired doing that.

Comment: Interesting, not sure how you would count successive observations curious to see to the answer if there is one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem can be split into two parts.  First you want to group by both `Id`, and consecutive elements in the `Event` series.  This can be accomplished using `shift` + `cumsum`

```
m = df.Event.ne(df.Event.shift()).cumsum()
df['count'] = df.groupby(['Id', m])['Event'].transform('size')

print(df)
```

```
   Id  Seqno. Event  count
0   1       2     A      1
1   1       3     B      1
2   1       5     A      3
3   1       6     A      3
4   1       7     A      3
5   1       8     B      1
6   1       9     C      1
7   1      10     D      1
```

This gives us a series that identifies sequential runs in our `Event` column, but now we want to make lookup simple.  We can `drop_duplicates`, so that each condition only returns a single run per `Id/Event/count`, and then use boolean indexing:

```
f = df[['Id', 'Event', 'count']].drop_duplicates()
f.loc[f.Event.eq('A') & f['count'].gt(2)]
```

```
   Id Event  count
2   1     A      3
```

Answer (score -1):

A function without using pandas internals, (which is arguably a better way to do this):

```
def eventmagic(event="A", num=2):
    subdf = df[(df["Event"] == event) & (df["Seqno."] > num)].sort_values(by="Seqno.")
    arr = subdf["Seqno."].values - np.arange(len(subdf)) # 5,6,7 to 5,5,5
    if len(arr) == 0: return 0
    i = 0
    while arr[i] == arr[0]:
        i += 1
        if i >= len(subdf):
            break
    return i

>>> eventmagic("B", 2)
1

>>> eventmagic("A", 1)
1

>>> eventmagic("A", 3)
3

>>> eventmagic("A", 10)
0
```

Comment: This is clearly not the output OP wanted, as you can see above :P

Comment: @RockyLi still incorrect.  This is a consecutive occurence problem.